# Row click event not working when datatables is on responsive mode or viewed on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

I have a code that looks like this

```
$('#mtable').DataTable( {
        "destroy": true,
        "bProcessing": true,
        "sAjaxSource": 'link of ajax',
        "aaSorting": [],
        responsive:true,
        "aoColumns": [
            { mData: 'col1' },
            { mData: 'col2' },
            { mData: 'col3' }
        ],
        "columnDefs": [
            { className: 'never', targets: 3 } 
        ]
    });
```

As you can see I have an option called `responsive:true`

and this is my code when clicking the row and get the value

```
$('#mtable tbody').on('dblclick', 'tr', function() {
    var col1 =  $(this).closest('tr').children()[1].textContent;
    alert(col1);       
});
```

Its working on the browser but when i click `CTRL SHIFT I` or turn to responsive the double click does not work.

How can I fix this?